# #docusignAPI get data time sent

Tags: date, docusignapi, signature

I use #docusignAPI and would like to get on my CRM data from the certificate
- date when sent
- date when opened
- Date when signed

Could you pls guide me how to get this data directly without manually opening the certificate?

Thanks a lot
see attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtEIT.png)

Answer (score 0):

A call to the [Envelopes::get method](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get) will return what you're looking for.

```
GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}
```

Response includes:

```
createdDateTime - When the initial draft was started
initialSentDateTime - When the envelope was sent
deliveredDateTime - When the envelope was viewed by the first recipient
completedDateTime - When the final signature was executed
```